# How do I lock the rotation of a grabbed object with Unity Oculus VR

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

For an Oculus Quest game i'm working on, I need to be able to grab an object and not rotate it in any way. I should be able to move it in the x, y and z axes though. I'm doing this in a climbing game and the object is quite big. My player is locked on (0,0,0) and you climb by grabbing the terrain and moving it, giving the illusion that you are climbing.

I am using Unity's Oculus integration asset and I have the OVR Grabbable script on the object I want to be able to grab.

How do I make sure that the object I'm grabbing, doesn't rotate at all?

I've tried using a rigidbody and locking the rotation of the wall I want to climb like that, but that doesn't work. Once I grab it, I can still rotate the object.

I have also tried locking the rotation of the hand rigidbody, but that setting seemed to be ignored, because I could still rotate the hands.

I've also tried adding a bit of code in the script, which would reset the objects rotation in the fixed update. I put this code in the OVR Grabbable script.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
}
```

Using this code didn't keep the wall from rotating, but it did snap back to rotation (0,0,0) every frame. THis caused the wall to function as if it would still rotate, but it looked like it was switching between (0,0,0) and the rotation it would be at in every frame. This is of course also not the desired result.

I am not using VRTK, because that does not work with the type of climbing I'm trying to achieve.

I would like to be able to grab an object, move it in the x, y and z axes, while it doesn't rotate at all. Currently, I can still rotate the object. How would I fix this issue and completely lock the rotation whenever I grab the object?

Comment: Have you tried putitng the code in LateUpdate instead?

Answer (score 3):

If the object has become a child of the hand and you still want it to move but not rotate. You could add a simple script which scores its default rotation and applies it in LateUpdate.

This is designed for non-physics objects so be sure to remove your test where you added the rigidbody to the wall.

Something simple like this would do the job.

```
Quaternion defaultRotation;

void Awake()
{
    defaultRotation = transform.rotation;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.rotation = defaultRotation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you want to find solution using the package's scripts :

1. Add a script component to the gameobject  *which hold the Grabbable script* named **OneGrabFreeTransformer** ( I'm using only one hand to grab , if you use both hands use *TwoGrabFreeTransformer*. ) Then check the 3 box of Constrain for each axis : [image: Screenshot for the One Grab Free Transformer Script]
2. Grab that *One Grab Free Transformer Script* component into Grabbable Component > Optionals > One Grab Free Transformer : [image]

That's it !

*Note : I'm using All-In-One SDK 62.0.0 , it bundles several Meta SDKs together , like interaction SDK as Oculus Integration did on the previous versions. If you use an old version of Oculus Integration, you may not find the components that I talked about or you may find different names. I advice you to migrate to the newest version of Oculus Integration, and it's better to migrate to All-In-One SDK.*